# How to show a watermark for 3 second on a MP4 using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I need to add a 3-second watermark to a Camera recorded video in Android. I'm using FFmpeg static build to execute the commands.

**Approach I**

I had tried the below command using latest version of FFmpeg(version N-60108-gda25a65) in my Desktop running Linux Mint, the command works fine.

```
ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 3 -i input.mp4 -i myImage.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,0\,3)"  -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

In Android I'm using the FFmpegv1.2 with below config to execute the command.

```
 *******Starting FFMPEG
    ***ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers***
    ***  built on Mar 31 2013 23:44:57 with gcc 4.6 (GCC) 20120106 (prerelease)***
    ***  configuration: --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/opt/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags= --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network***
    ***  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100***
    ***  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100***
    ***  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104***
    ***  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103***
    ***  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103***
    ***  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100***
    ***  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102***
```

Java Code to run the FFmpeg command:

```
String[] ffmpegCommandToAddWatermark = { 
            mFfmpegInstallPath, "-y", "-itsoffset","3",
             "-i", INPUT_VIDEO_PATH, "-i", WATERMARK_IMAGE_PATH,
             "-filter_complex","[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:between(t\\,0\\,3)",
             "-strict","-2",
             "-codec:a","copy",OUTPUT_VIDEO_PATH};          
        try {
        Process ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommandToAddWatermark)
            .redirectErrorStream(true).start();

        String line;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));
        Log.d(TAG, "*******Starting FFMPEG");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {

            Log.d(TAG, "***" + line + "***");
        }
        Log.d(null, "****ending FFMPEG****");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The command execution failed with following error:

```
***[overlay @ 0x271f770] No option name near 'between(t,0,3)'***
***[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2711530] Error initializing filter 'overlay' with args '0:0:between(t,0,3)'***
***Error configuring filters.***
```

The same command executes successfully when `:enable=between(t\,0\,3)` is removed, but the resulting output video has the watermark throughout the timeline, but I need watermark only for the starting 3 seconds.

**Approach II**:

I tried to convert WaterMarkImage to WaterMarkVideo

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 30 -i WaterMarkImage.jpg -b:v "4096k" -vf "scale=640:480" -t 3 WaterMarkVideo.mp4
```

And then merge the WaterMarkVideo.mp4+CameraRecordedVideo.mp4 using the concat command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

The resulting output is corrupt due to BitRate,FrameRate,etc., mismatch. Any idea to solve the problem?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg 1.2 does not have [timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) support. Please refer to your local FFmpeg documentation when using old releases. The online [FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) is synced daily with the source code, and because [FFmpeg development is very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=tree) the online documentation may not be suitable for your old release.

Releases are intended for distributors. General users should use the most recent source code from git master.

Comment: I'm just curious to know whether FFmpeg(1.2) supports any other feature other than Timeline Editing to hide the Overlay, From the [changelog](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/Changelog) I can infer that Overlay was introduced in v0.8 but Timeline Editing was introduced in v2.0 only.